# angular history route and fragment

Tags: angular, routes, fragment, markdown, history

my angular app use the history route path

`localhost/blog/article/:id`

when this route on open `localhost/blog/article/123456`, httpclient get some markdown content data and render

the markdown content

```markdown
- [one](#one)
- [two](#two)

# one
some thing

# two
some thing
```

render html

```html
<a herf="#one">one</a>
<a herf="#two">two</a>
<h1 id="one">one</h1>
<p>some thing</p>
<h1 id="two">one</h1>
<p>some thing</p>
```

but click the a tag redirect to root path

how to scroll to the fragment when clicking on a tag

---------UPDATE---------

The problem has been solved

[refer to here](https://github.com/jfcere/ngx-markdown/issues/125#issuecomment-573433121)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable anchorScrolling in RouterModule.forRoot() like below :-

```
RouterModule.forRoot({anchorScrolling: true})
```

And use fragment attribute to assign the fragment like above instead of href.

```
<a [routerLink]='"."' [fragment]="one">Dashboard</a>
```

You can read about it here :-

https://medium.com/dev-genius/advanced-router-configuration-in-angular-d22c6dc420be

Or :-

https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions

Comment: can't use fragment attribute,because makerdown component according to standard render `[one](#one)` html content is `<a href="#one">one</a>`,so i don't know what to do